# Generic ODBC remote source in SAP HANA SDI/SDA

Tags: hana

Has anyone been able to create in SAP HANA a Generic ODBC remote source for a database other than MSSQL/Oracle/Netezza/ASE -- in other words, where you'd have to select a datasource "Generic ODBC" and then likely implement your own property/configuration file.

I'm trying to configure this on top of an Apache Drill ODNBC driver. I am able to successfully test System DSN using iSQL utility, but Remote Source creation fails with an error message citing problems loading the driver file -- a rather cryptic one.

I'm in the middle of an exchange with OSS, but so far they seem to be reluctant to accept it as a product fault. I'd like to see if there are successful cases for Generic ODBC in HANA at all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's supported.
Every ODBC source type must have all its capabilities described.
This is required to map datatypes, functions and features.

What you can do is replace an existing odbc source.
For instance you can change the file config/property_ntz.ini to create a valid description of the capabilities of apache drill. From the HANA side, just declare it as a netezza. 
If it makes sense to support Apache drill, as an SAP employee myself I could trigger a discussion internally.

Comment: yeah I understand the purpose of property_*.ini files. I tried a few things with those files and found what I believe inconsistencies in HANA behaviour, which I had reported to OSS. If you're interested for a message#, I can give it. Other than that, I was asking about details of a successful implementation of a Generic ODBC driver, which, it seems, no one has yet done.

Comment: I've been finally able to establish a connection, and I can see my schemas and views. However, when trying to add them as virtual tables I'm getting an error in the backend, telling that the query "SELECT TOP 1 from <my source>" can't be executed. Are you aware if there's a reason to use such syntax as opposed to adding "limit 1" to the end of the statement like any other SQL would do?

Comment: ah, this syntax must be relevant to Adapter Name I picked (it was Hadoop(ODBC)". I created a new destination with adapter "MSSQL(ODBC)", and syntax is different, but still not one that Drill likes: SELECT * FROM "dfs.tmp"."v_weblogs" WHERE 1 = 2 -- any idea how I can enforce using the character ` instead of " ? It doesn't seem to be referred to in the property file

Comment: they also say in the doco on property file, 'The set of definable properties is fixed based on the existing infrastructure in SAP HANA.' -- is there any way to get a full list of properties available?